# Is URI if form “scheme:/path” valid?

Tags: java, uri

I used this code to create URI in Java:

```
new URI(/*scheme*/ "scheme", /*host*/ null, /*path*/ "/42", /*fragment*/ null);
```

When I convert this URI to string, I get `scheme:/42`. Is URI in format `scheme:/path` valid?

---

When I use `new URI("scheme", "", "/path", null)` I get `scheme:///path`. I know this is valid (like `file:///` URIs). Do these URIs have different meaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Wikipedia article on URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uniform_Resource_Identifier&oldid=891155192#Definition) and [diagram on Wikimedia Commons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:URI_syntax_diagram.png):

> `URI = scheme:[//authority]path[?query][#fragment]`
>
> […]
>
> [image: <code>URI = scheme:[//authority]path[?query][#fragment]</code>]

The `//authority` (user+password+host+port) part can be skipped. The `path` component *includes* `/` after `//authority` part.

---

This URI **is** valid.

Comment: It depends on the URI scheme, no? For example, a HTTP URI [must have](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-2.7.1) the authority component (and it can’t be empty), so neither `http:/path` nor `http:///path` are valid URIs.

Comment: @unor, My question is about general URI syntax. I know some schemes can limit it.